# Using 32bit COM addin under MS Office 64 bit

Tags: com, 64-bit, ms-office, add-in, 32-bit

I am struggling to apply an existing 32bit COM addin to 64bit Microsoft Word 2010.

To make the addin visible to Word, I have used the dllsurrogate-method, as it described [here](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/).

The problem is that now addin caused some strange exception when tries to add its toolbar and menu to office's. I cannot figure out, what it is, it seems, that the command bar reference became not valid in unpredicable moments.

Can anyone explain this?

Note, that everething is fine when I use the same addin under 32bit Microsoft Word 2010 and more old versions of Ms Office.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337134/how-can-i-adapt-a-32-bit-vb6-application-to-work-with-64-bit-office/8339149#8339149

Answer (score 5, accepted):

32-bit add-ins are [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility) on 64-bit. [Microsoft recommends](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx) to use the 32-bit version of Office unless you run into the memory limitations of a 32-bit process which is only likely to happen if you need to deal with extremely large spreadsheets:

> The recommendations for which edition of Office 2010 to install are as follows:
>
> - If users in your organization depend on existing extensions to Office, such as ActiveX controls, third-party add-ins, in-house solutions built on previous versions of Office, or 32-bit versions of programs that interface directly with Office, we recommend that you install 32-bit Office 2010 (the default installation) on computers that are running both 32-bit and 64-bit supported Windows operating systems.
> - If some users in your organization are Excel expert users who work with Excel spreadsheets that are larger than 2 gigabytes (GB), they can install the 64-bit edition of Office 2010. In addition, if you have in-house solution developers, we recommend that those developers have access to the 64-bit edition of Office 2010 so that they can test and update your in-house solutions on the 64-bit edition of Office 2010.

If you need to go with the 64-bit version because of the memory limitations you have [the following options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility):

> - If you have the source code, you can generate a 64-bit version yourself,
> - You can contact the vendor for an updated version,
> - You can search for an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, 0xA3. Its really a pity, because the addin seems to work right, just unability to build itself in office's UI.

Comment: i developed outlook add-in using windows xp + .net 2005 + vsto 2005 + PIA 2003. it working fine in 32 bit versions. now i need the application to run in 64 os with 64 bit office. how to develop 64 bit version outlook addin? what are the required s/w needed to develop 64 bit outlook addin?

Comment: @KumaranT: Please note that the usage of the 64-bit version of Office is not recommended by Microsoft unless you need to handle extremely large Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: now customers are using outlook 2010 64 bit with 64 bit operating system which is available in market. i need to provide an outlook 2010 64 bit add-in to make work in it. so i need how to develop 64 bit version outlook addin? what are the required s/w needed to develop 64 bit outlook addin? it will assist me to make a move.

Comment: @DirkVollmar-0xA3 is there any way to  generate a 64-bit version  of office addin if am having the source code...??

Comment: @Arshad: In what language is your add-in written? I haven't done this myself, but you basically would have to compile to x64 and then register your COM classes / add-in in the 64-bit branch of the Registry. However, this only works if your add-in doesn't have any 32-bit dependencies, e.g. to MSComCtl.

Comment: @DirkVollmar-0xA3 written in C# and setup was made in WIX

Comment: That should work fine, unless you have any 32-bit dependencies. Also don't forget to create a 64-bit installer.

Comment: @DirkVollmar-0xA3 32-bit dependencies.? what does it means..?

Comment: It means that you should not reference any 32-bit COM components or 32-bit .NET assemblies in your add-in. You also need to be extra careful when using native interop (`DllImport`).