# Excel error linking C++: "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Tags: c++, excel, dll, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I wrote a simple C++ program

Source.cpp:

```
double __stdcall square(double& x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Define.def:

```
LIBRARY "square" 
EXPORTS
square
```

Then in my .xlsm file Modules, added module1 importing:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function square _
Lib "C:\Users\user\Documents\AthosCode\Marek Kolman Square\Square\Debug\square.dll" _
(ByRef x As Double) As Double
```

and in Sheet1, put `10` in A1, and `=square(A1)` in B1.

The error says: "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type".

What's the problem and how could I fix it?

My environment is

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2016 Community (so it's 32-bit)
- Excel 2016 64-bit

---

Replying the comment, if I change passing by reference to passing by value, the error is the same.

I changed the Source.cpp to

```
double __stdcall square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

and changed the module1 as

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function square _
Lib "C:\Users\user\Documents\AthosCode\Marek Kolman Square\Square\Debug\square.dll" _
(ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

Same error.

Comment: Why pass by reference? Pass by value should be sufficient.

Comment: @songyuanyao same error. pls see the post updated.

Comment: Did you set A1 cell format as double? Perhaps excel interpreting it as a string.

Comment: There's [no 64-bit VS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2516436/995714). What's important is if your dll has been compiled in 32 or 64-bit mode, not VS version

Comment: @Ari0nhh no it's not the problem. If put "10.5" in A1 and "=A1*A1" in B1, it works.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks for the tip! I changed the compilation setting from "Debug, x86" to "Debug, x64", now the error disappear! So does it mean that 32 bits DLL could not be imported into Excel 64-bits?

Comment: Bittness of the `dll` and `exe` should match. x64 exe could not load x32 dll and vice versa.

Comment: @Ari0nhh thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the differences in architecture, it's impossible to [load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265023/995714) and vice versa

It's possible to [access 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code](https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) but unless you have legacy DLLs without a 64-bit version, you should compile as a 64-bit project. And [64-bit Office doesn't support 32-bit plugin at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945847/995714) so you'll need a 64-bit DLL.

- [Can I load a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/225151/995714)
- [Process Interoperability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)